# Selecting matrix elements from a column matrix

Tags: python, numpy

I want to select a element from each row in a matrix according a column matrix.
The column matrix thus contains the indexes to pick.

```
(Pdb) num_samples
15000
(Pdb) probs.shape
(15000, 26)
(Pdb) y.shape
(15000, 1)
(Pdb) (probs[np.arange(num_samples),y]).shape
(15000, 15000)
(Pdb) # this should (15000,)
```

Comment: Try `y.ravel()` for indexing?

Comment: y.ravel()
*** AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'ravel'

Comment: `y.values.ravel()` maybe?

Comment: or `y[:,0]` - one way or other `y` needs to a 1d that matches the `np.arange()` in size.  If it is a (n,1) array, then the arange is broadcast to (1,n), and together to (n,n).  Play with this on small sample arrays.

Answer (score 1):

[integer array indexing](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html#integer-array-indexing) may be helpful.
Suppose you have this `numpy` array:

```
myArray = numpy.array([[2, 3, 4],
                       [6, 7, 8],
                       [9, 1, 5]])
```

If your array of indices to select is

```
indices = numpy.array([2, 0, 1])
```

Then

```
rowSelector = numpy.arange(myArray.shape[0])
myArray[rowSelector, indices]
```

returns the values of the selected elements of the array:

```
array([4, 6, 1])
```

Answer (score 0):

It may be that your `y` variable is a numpy matrix. Your code works fine when `y` is a list:

```
>>> num_samples = 3
>>> data = np.matrix([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]])
>>> y = [0, 1, 2]
>>> print((data[np.arange(num_samples), y]).shape)
(1, 3)
```

and the result can be easily rearranged to be a column matrix.